# Can adaboost choose the same variable for multiple splits for a given tree?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

Can adaboost choose the same variable for multiple splits for a given tree?

The model was given 100 + variable to choose from and it did choose them for the other trees in the ensemble.

I am using gbm package

->  var_1 (<= 0.7197815 )
 ->  ->  var_1 (<= 0.306903 )
 ->  ->  ->  0.04056787
 ->  ->  var_1 (> 0.306903 )
 ->  ->  ->  -0.02655625
 ->  var_1 (> 0.7197815 )
 ->  ->  var_1 (<= 2.922242 )
 ->  ->  ->  0.005732073
 ->  ->  var_1 (> 2.922242 )
 ->  ->  ->  0.03265469

Answer (score 1):

a) Adaboost does not perform feature selection or variable selection. The weak learner you use might (which you are usually using a tree, but don't have to).

With that in mind, your question really is:

b) Can a decision tree use the same variable to split on multiple times in a row?

The answer is yes. Consider the case where you have only 1 feature. The decision tree must use that one feature multiple times. Since you have 100+ features and it is still using that one variable multiple times - you can infer from your model that var_1 is very important for making a decision about your problem.